# Angular/Typescript: Readonly modifier is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

**I am trying to make a property in a component read-only.** However, it seems like the readonly modifier doesn't do anything at all.

[**Example stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3a1p1x)

Based on the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier), I shouldn't be able to modify the `cars` property declared in AppComponent once I have initialized in the `constructor()`.

**What I've tried:**

At first I was able to modify `cars` in AppComponent's `ngOnInit()` and I thought that this is probably an *allowed* behaviour because the component is still being "constructed". So I created a button that calls a function and tries to modify the property, yet, again I could do so. So I thought maybe the readonly modifier only applies to outside classes accessing the property. But yet, again I am able to modify `cars` in `HelloComponent`.

Am I using readonly wrongly? How do I use it correctly or make a property accessible in public but not "modified-able" (readonly) by outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**readonly**
This keyword is used in interface or class to mark a property as ready only

```
class Employee {
    readonly empCode: number;
    empName: string;

    constructor(code: number, name: string)     {
        this.empCode = code;
        this.empName = name;
    }
}
let emp = new Employee(10, "John");
emp.empCode = 20; //Compiler Error
emp.empName = 'Bill'; //Compiler Error
```

Note that property marked readonly can be only assigned value in constructor or when declaring the property.

A property marked readyonly can not be reassigned.

In your code example:

```
 modifyCars() {
    this.cars[0] = { id: -1, name: 'MODIFIED BY BUTTON' };
  }
```

You are not reassigning, instead you are mutating array. To prevent array mutation you can use ReadOnly mapped type.

replace

```
  readonly cars;
```

with

```
readonly cars: Readonly<{ id: number, name: string }[]>;
```

[Full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfpbnd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail, that makes a lot sense. Anyway, fyi, your stackblitz doesn't work though. Not that it matters cause your answer does explain everything but do remember to press the fork button next time =P

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about link.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeScript comes with a ReadonlyArray type that is the same as
>   Array with all mutating methods removed, so you can make sure you
>   don’t change your arrays after creation

```
 cars :ReadonlyArray<any>;
```

Forked Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8pmdr

Ref:https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-properties